# Dataframe.mean() returning Series[]

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to python and programming. Although I have been looking every where to resolve this issue, I am not having any luck.

I am working on a dataframe that has been created from the python binance API. For some reason I get the following output when I run dataframe.mean() - Series([], dtype: float64)

I was expecting the mean for each of the 6 columns contained within the dataframe. I assume this is returning an empty series.

Can someone please help me out by explaining what it is returning. I am able to run the dataframe.median() function successfully therefore I assume it may have something to do with the type within the dataframe.

Thanks in advance.

T

Comment: Probably because your columns are not numerical. You can confirm by `print(df.dtypes)`

Comment: Can you put up an example of your dataframe and your code?

Comment: Yes - they are listed all as objects based on the print(df.dtypes) - how do I convert to numerical values?

Comment: Thanks to Quang Hoang. This was what I needed to do. Thanks for the quick response - I really appreciate it.